# Trouble adding IPv6 static route in netplan

Tags: netplan

I'm having trouble getting netplan to accept this IPv6 static route:

**sudo ip -6 route add fec0:abcd:250:1::6/64 via fe80::8ad9:8f00:93d6:4960 dev ens1f1**

In my yaml file I've tried:

```
 ens1f1:
      routes:
      - to: "fec0:abcd:250:1::6/64"
        via: "fe80::8ad9:8f00:93d6:4960"
```

But I get an error that the yaml file cannot be loaded:

```
Error while loading /etc/netplan/interfaces.yaml, aborting.
```

Adding the IPv6 route via the ip command works fine and produces the expected results. Any suggestions on what to try in netplan?

Answer (score 0):

In the quoted yaml, you are missing a colon after the interface name.

Comment: That was a copy/paste mistake, edited the original. Thanks for taking a look.